Using workflows from one Camunda Spring Boot Application in another via JAR Packaging
I have two Camunda Spring Boot applications, and I want to use some DMNs from one application in the other. Is it possible to package one application as a JAR and use it in the other application?

It is important that you use the @EnableProcessApplication annotation on your application/configuration. Jars are scanned for deployable resources when they contain a META-INF/processes.xml file (it can be empty). Those two setups together allow you to scan for (DMN) resources and auto deploy them on application start.
That being said: It might be possible to include one spring application as a jar dependency into another application, but I won't bother to figure this out. Instead I would provide a shared jar that contains the DMN reosurces and the processes.xml marker and include that in both apps.
